# How do they film money in TV or movie?

Tags: production, props

Money shown in movies or TV shows before 30-40 years was looked fake. Is there a law that prohibits was showing real money (bills and close ups of coins) in a TV commercial, show or film? How do they film now?  Having real money around makes for a real headache if (or when) it comes up missing, isn't it? Is that money belongs to production house or do they get money from any agency which looks real but it's not?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> **Stage Money**
>
> To create the illusion of massive wads of cash, TV and film producers
>   don't take real $100 bills and put them on the front and back of a
>   stack of $1 bills (or even just pieces of paper cut to size) but
>   instead use fake bills.
>
> This is also seen any time where the character shows a bunch of bills.
>   Rather than going to the bank and getting, say $5,000 in real money,
>   letting the actor use it for the scene and then putting it back in the
>   bank, they use Stage Money.
>
> There's actually a cottage industry that makes fake money to be used
>   in films, that looks just enough like the real thing that a casual
>   viewing doesn't reveal that they're fake... for one example, take a
>   look [here](http://www.scripophily.net/autmovmon.html). Users of Poser software can freely download U.S. money
>   props, including various coins and four different currency styles. The
>   20th century bill props are not intended to imitate genuine currency.
>
> It isn't legal for print media to use real money, to the point that
>   boxers with accurately sized money on it were once seized. So the
>   magazine ad would show part of a hundred dollar bill, but not all of
>   it. Because the law says that only the government can print money.
>   There is no law against showing it on TV or in the movies, since you
>   can't cut out the bills and use them.
>
> In Britain, if a TV game show has a prize draw with cash prizes and
>   illustrates them, the £10, £20 or £50 notes will be shown in full but
>   with something like "SPECIMEN" superimposed. In some other parts of
>   the world, bank notes illustrated in print media (such as ads) often
>   also have that SPECIMEN marking.
>
> **Examples**:
>
> - Doctor Who had some specially commissioned notes made with portraits
>     of David Tennant and (producer) Phil Collinson on them for The
>     Christmas Invasion. This was for legal reasons, though, and now these
>     props go for a pretty penny on eBay.
> - The reason Doctor Who used fake notes may have been not so much that they weren't allowed to use real currency, but that the
>     scene involved a cash machine malfunctioning and shooting banknotes
>     across the street. There'd be too much risk of the notes becoming
>     damaged or getting pocketed by the extras who scrabble across the
>     street collecting the notes. It's not an offence to show currency on
>     British TV, but it is an offence to damage or destroy it.
> - Notably averted in Art Attack, where Neil Buchanan made a vast portrait of the queen out of hundreds of thousands of pounds worth of
>     real £10 notes, which the Bank of England lent him.
> - Harry Enfield's early character Loadsamoney's "wad" used the first method described above, being two real £10 notes with lots of
>     appropriately cut newspaper in between.
> - Real Life example: During the Victorian era, forging a banknote carried a hefty sentence, but making something that looked a bit like
>     a banknote didn't. So forgers would create notes that read "Bank of
>     Engraving" instead of "Bank of England", and could try to pass these
>     off as real currency.
> - The setting of the 2005 adaptation of Charlie and the Chocolate Factory was designed to look like America to Britons and like Britain
>     to Americans, made use of "guinea" notes that didn't look quite like
>     either a $10 bill or a £10 note.
> - To someone who goes to Chinatown often enough, it's obvious when someone is using Chinese Hell dollars as stand-ins for American
>     dollars, but otherwise the designs are quite similar. They were used
>     like that in an episode of the Australian series Pizza.
> - The Stephen Sondheim musical Road Show involved piles of cash being literally thrown into the air until they carpeted the stage, so
>     that audience members in the front few rows were able to catch loose
>     bills. Needless to say, it wasn't real money.
> - In Making Money, the Ankh-Morpork Times broke the story of Moist von Lipwig's new invention, paper currency, by averting this trope.
> - They printed true-to-scale images of the front and back of a bank
>     note, which (as Vetinari observes) surely sent most of the city
>     scrambling for scissors and glue.
> - A related trick in real life: the "carnie roll", a roll of what appears to be high-denomination bills. The first and last ones are
>     high-denomination bills, though all of the ones in-between are $1
>     bills.
> - One short from The Three Stooges has them needing to get the ransom for a starlet. They resort to some bills found in a room
>     marked 'Property'. It didn't say whose property, of course. Guess
>     what the roll was identified by the crooks as...
> - On the NBC game show Scrabble, players could earn bonus cash by placing letters in colored squares on the gameboard and then
>     immediately guessing the word in play. Host Chuck Woolery would then
>     pay out the bonus in pink or blue "Chuck Bucks," fake bills printed
>     with his picture.

[(Source: TV Tropes)](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StageMoney)

Comment: Great answer Ankit, you beat me to it :) Here's another link to a company that supplies fake money: http://www.anythingbutcostumes.com/catalog/?mode=showcat&id=341

Answer (score 9):

In the US the [**Secret Service**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Secret_Service) isn't just responsible for the protection of the *President*, it also deals with *financial crimes*, like ***counterfeiting money***.

From [their website](http://www.secretservice.gov/money_illustrations.shtml):

> **The law sharply restricts photographs or other printed reproductions of paper currency**, checks, bonds, revenue stamps and securities of the United States and foreign governments.

but

> The ***Counterfeit Detection Act of 1992***, *Public Law 102-550*, in *Section 411 of Title 31* of the *Code of Federal Regulations*, **permits color illustrations of U.S. currency provided**:
>
> - The illustration is of a size less than three-fourths or more than one and one-half, in linear dimension, of each part of the item illustrated
> - The illustration is one-sided
> - All negatives, plates, positives, digitized storage medium, graphic files, magnetic medium, optical storage devices, and any other thing used in the making of the illustration that contain an image of the illustration or any part thereof are destroyed and/or deleted or erased after their final use

This mean ***prop/stage money* needs to conform to certain restrictions**.

---

However, **filming real money for use in a movie is allowed** under [18 U.S.Code § 504](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/504):

> Notwithstanding any other provision of this chapter, the following are permitted:
>
> - ...
> - (3) **The making or importation of motion-picture films**, microfilms, or slides, **for projection upon a screen or for use in telecasting**...

---

So, one can either use

- *prop money (which, obviously, is not allowed to be a perfect copy)*,

  [image: Axel Foley] <sup>[[Source](http://www.propstore.com/product-Axel-Foley-s--Eddie-Murphy--Kiss-My-Ass-Wonder-Dollars.htm)]</sup>
- or *real money*